# Gremlin, how to return all vertex pairs that are connected by an edge with a specific label

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Take a simple example of airline connection graph as in below picture

[image]
can we come up with a gremlin query that can return pairs of cities connected by SW? Like `[{ATL,CHI},{SFO,CHI},{DAL,CHI},{HSV,DAL}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all you probably need is:

```
g.V().outE('SW').inV().path()
```

If you don't want the edge in the result you can use a `flatMap` :

```
g.V().flatMap(outE('SW').inV()).path()
```

To get back some properties rather than just vertices all you need to do is add a `by` modulator to the `path` step.

```
g.V().flatMap(outE('SW').inV()).path().by(valueMap())
```

This will return all the properties for every vertex. In a large result set this is not considered a best practice and you should explicitly ask for the properties you care about. There are many ways you can do this using `values`, `project` or `valueMap`. If you had a property called `code` representing the airport code you might do this.

```
g.V().
  flatMap(outE('SW').inV()).
  path().
    by(valueMap('code'))
```

or just

```
g.V().flatMap(outE('SW').inV()).
  path().
    by('code')
```

Comment: Thank you. This gives me path, but how can I get the valueMap of vertices instead? looking for response which has values instead of reference to vertices

Comment: I have something like this g.V().flatMap(outE('SW').inV()).path().map(\_\_.unfold().map(\_\_.valueMap()).fold()). want to check if there is a better way to do it

Comment: I have added more examples to the answer. As you are just starting out with Gremlin you may find this guide helpful: http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html